# python-rq - how do I wait for the entire queue to be handled?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I'm enqueueing several jobs to a `rq.Queue` and want to wait (not busy wait) until the queue is empty and all jobs were handled. Is there such an event to listen to?

Comment: Have you arrived at any solution?